# My sudo rights expired after a few hours of operation

Tags: linux, permissions

I was observing the following behaviour:

py script:

```
os.mkdir(path) #all OK
operations_that_take_10hrs_to_complete()
os.mkdir(path) # permission denied
```

like I lost my sudo rights after some time ..

Comment: Do you have access to the root account so that you can change the sudoers file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As stated in the sudo man page, the default timeout is 15 minutes. You can change this timeout in the sudoers file by adding this row (where 30 is half an hour):

```
Defaults timestamp_timeout=30
```

Comment: the timeout is there for a reason. changing it to >10h just for one stupid script is 1) ridiculous and 2) totally unnecessary.